# How to instruct the LaTeX engine to search up the folder tree from files embedded via the `input` command?

Tags: input

I take a course that gives weekly homework assignments. I created a folder `mycourse` for the course, with subfolders `mycourse/hw1/`, `mycourse/hw2/`, etc. for every homework assignment. I have a `mycourse/urpreamble.tex` file in the course's folder, and additionally every subfolder contains a `preamble.tex` file, e.g. `mycourse/hw1/preamble.tex`, `mycourse/hw2/preamble.tex`, etc. Additionally, each subfolder contains a `answers.tex` file. This file is a LaTeX document, which is intended to by typeset with LaTeX as a pdf file which I will submit to the professor. Each `answers.tex` file is structured as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\input{preamble}
...
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

I would like each `preamble.tex` file to begin by inputting the contents of `urpreamble.tex`. However, the naive method of writing `\input{urpreamble}` in the beginning of the `preamble.tex` file doesn't work: the LaTeX engine complains that the file was not found. Is there a way to instruct the LaTeX engine to search up the folder tree? I tried `\input{../urpreamble}`, but this doesn't work. However, even if it did work, I'd rather have a more general solution that searches up the folder tree even beyond the immediately preceding parent.

Comment: it should be `\input{../urpreamble}` not `\input{../Preamble}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You're right. Corrected.

Comment: `\input{../urpreamble}, but this doesn't work.` what do you mean by "does not work"? It will work if there is a file `urpreamble.tex` in the parent of the current directory unless you have set the security options to ban all access to  `..`

Comment: how do you run latex? If you use `pdflatex hw1/file.tex` then it should be `\input{urpreamble}` If you use  `cd hw1; pdflatex file.tex` then it should be `\input{../urpreamble}`

Comment: your description do not sound right but if you set `TEXINPUTS=/path/to/mycourse//:`  then any files below mycourse will be found wherever you run latex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. Your comments were helpful. The problem is resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you run `pdflatex answers.tex` from the `hw1` subdirectory `\input{../urpreamble}` will work unless you have security settings preventing access  to `..`.

Note paths are relative to the working directory of the tex process, not relative to the file, so if you are in the parent and run `pdflatex hw1/answers.tex` then it should be `\input{urpreamble}`. (This is a confusing feature of tex and it's always best to *not* reference the file via a path on the command line. `cd` to the directory then use a local file name, so the working directory of the process is the directory containing the file and `\input{abc}` can be taken as relative to either.

texlive's texmf.cnf for example has

```
% Do we allow TeX \input or \openin (openin_any), or \openout
% (openout_any) on filenames starting with `.' (e.g., .rhosts) or
% outside the current tree (e.g., /etc/passwd)?
% a (any)        : any file can be opened.
% r (restricted) : disallow opening dot files
% p (paranoid)   : as `r' and disallow going to parent directories, and
%                  restrict absolute paths to be under $TEXMFOUTPUT.
openin_any = a
openout_any = p
```

So by default you can read but not write to `..` but you may have changed that.

Otherwise, you can not search up but you can search down from an arbitrary point so if you set

```
TEXINPUTS=/path/to/mycourse//:
```

then any files below `mycourse` will be found whereever you run latex

Comment: Thanks. For future reference could you please add to your answer the information you provided in [this comment to my original post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664384/how-to-instruct-the-latex-engine-to-search-up-the-folder-tree-from-files-embedde#comment1652222_664384), that "If you use pdflatex hw1/file.tex then it should be \input{urpreamble}"?

Comment: @EvanAad ah that was the issue;-)  That is why the answer starts `Assuming you run...` but I'll add a line about the case that assumption is false.

Comment: @EvanAad new (2nd) paragraph added